# useCallback usage on arrow function as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm confused with below code

```
<Signup onClick={() => {}} />
```

Then in the in the Signup component, I saw the usage of useCallback like so

```
const Signup = ({onClick}) => {
   const handleClick = useCallback((e) => {e.preventDefault();},[e])
   return <a onClick={handleClick}>signup</a>
}
```

what is the intention of using the useCallback? can't it just be

```
const Signup = ({onClick}) => <a onClick={(e) => e.preventDefault();onClick()}>signup</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main purpose of `useCallback` is that on each render of the parent component it does not create a new reference to a function that does the exact same thing as the old function. And creating this new reference will mean that the old function and the new function are not the same - even though they do the same thing, which causes a render.

With `useCallback` It's still the same reference to the same function on a render (assuming it's dependencies didn't change). So anything that depends on this function does not re-evaluate (ie if it's a dependency in `useEffect`, `useMemo`, a prop to a component, etc.).

So in the example case `Signup` will only re-render if `onClick` changes. But otherwise, it's good.

In your example, `Signup` will always re-render because the function to `onClick` will always be a new reference anytime the parent re-renders. To be clear, in `<Signup onClick={() => {}} />` the function `() = {}` should also use useCallback to make what I said true.

I've seen a lot of articles on how the extra processing of `useCallback` and `useMemo` isn't worth it always, and you should only use it when you know it will create a benefit. This is 100% academically true. But in my humble experience, not using it leads to re-renders and sometimes infinite loops in `useEffect` in complex components. If I'm unsure, I use it. If I were smarter, I'd be sure I guess. But I don't use `useCallback` when I know I don't need it. Otherwise, I do. (As opposed to I only use it when I know I need it)

Comment: so you can freely use arrow function in whenever you want? like passing down through prop without caring potential rendering issue? you say avoid it unless you need it, when you will you know you need it? when the app become lag?

Comment: An arrow function, or any created function, will be a new thing on each render. So every reference to that new thing will update. It's probably not a performance issue in most cases and is fine.